# Execute a javascript function only if session["x"]="ok"; if it is not, not execute!

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Well i have 2 aspx
page1 you are going to have amm two buttons or it dontmind but the goal is...

when user press button1 in page1.aspx, session["x"] will be equals to "ok"
if users press button2 in page1.aspx, session["x"] will be eauls to null;

so after press any button user will be redirected to page2.aspx.

i want to execute a javascript function if session is equals to "ok" and not to do it
if session is null, someidea? when page2.aspx is open javascript function will be done automatically, if it is null, javascript function will not be nothing or it will not be executed. some idea? thanks guys!

it worked so...

the real code was it..

```
<% if (Session[@"codigodiagrama"] != null){%>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload=  function () {
               alert('with code');
           }

       </script> 
     <% } %>

      <% if (Session[@"codigodiagrama"] == null){%>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           window.onload= function () {
               alert('null');
           }


       </script> 
     <% } %>
```

now i want to pass the session["codigodiagrama"] to the function
if it has code to pass the String (codigodiagrama)

i refer how to pass this session to this windows.onload =function(pass code here)

Comment: as accepted? sorry but i dont know to use very good this page, my english is not very good, how do i mark answers as accepted man? thank you..

Comment: Click the check mark next to the answer you think is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page2 aspx you could have something like below...

```
<% if(Session[@"x"] == @"ok") { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SomeFunction();
</script>
<% } %>
```

**EDIT**

In response to additional information in question...

You can achieve your goal like so..

```
<% if (Session[@"codigodiagrama"] != null){%>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function () {
         alert('with code <%= Session[@"codigodiagrama"] %>');
     };
   </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: @angel Somewhere in the ASPX page.. wherever you would normally execute the javascript.

Comment: @angel I modified my answer to address the additional information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

in the page2 aspx in the code behind:

declare Public sessionX as string

in the page_init event set sessionX = session("x")

use it in the javascript function

var x

x = '<%=sessionX%>';

if (x.toString() == 'ok') {

alert('hello');}